# PDR glue removal taking flecks of paint with it. Any way to avoid?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches, dent, pdr

I've got a 34 year old car. I bought a PDR kit to remove some minor dents. It's working but removing the glue is taking a few flecks of paint with it.

Is this to do with the age of the car? Or is there some other glue I could use for older paint? Or is there some technique I can use to try to avoid this?

Comment: how are you removing the glue?

Comment: @HandyHowie often it comes off with the pull tab. Other times I have to spray it with  methylated spirits and slowly pull it off.